# What does CompareTo() do? IComparable

Tags: c#, icomparable

I am using IComparable and a IComparer

**In the Student class:[IComparable]**

```
    public int CompareTo(Student studentToCompare)
    {
        if (this.Number < studentToCompare.Number)
            return 1;
        else if (this.Number > studentToCompare.Number)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

**In the StudentCompareName class: [IComparer]**

```
    public int Compare(Student x, Student y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
```

With Compare(Student x, Student y) I am sorting the list of students on name.

If I dont use a CompareTo() in the Student-class, I'm getting errors.

I wonder why I need to have a CompareTo() in my main (Student) class, and what does it do? Why do I need to compare first the student number in the Student class and after that I'm allowed to sort on name in the StudentCompareName class?

Comment: Can you define "I'm getting errors" a bit more thoroughly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am using IComparable and a IComparer

That's the source of the confusion. You only need *one* of the two - and they'd rarely be implemented in the same class.

`IComparable<T>` is implemented to give a *natural* comparison between one object and another. In the case of something like `Student`, that probably doesn't make sense, as there are multiple ways to compare students. On the other hand, for something like `DateTime` it makes perfect sense.

`IComparer<T>` is meant to be a custom comparison - so it makes sense to have a `StudentNameComparer` which implements `IComparer<Student>` by comparing the names, for example.

Comment: Does it make sense to say: `IComparable<T>` can be used to compare an instance with another, while `IComparer<T>` which is for custom comparison can be used in a `StudentNameComparer` that takes two instance and compares them. is this ok?

Comment: @DarthVader: No - `StudentNameComparer` wouldn't *use* an `IComparer<T>`, it would *be* an `IComparer<T>`. It would be *used* by something like `Sort`.

Comment: That s what I meant, got it. Meanwhile, can u suggest with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221430/consume-from-queue-with-multiple-threads-tasks

Comment: I used an IComparer and created an instance of it. StudentNameComparer snc = new StudentNameComparer(). After that I did listStudents.Sort(snc). Is that good? It works..

Comment: @xVizzi: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

`IComparable` is an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), meaning it defines methods that *must* be implemented in your inheriting class.  It's simply your implementation of what "Compare" means to your object(s).

Answer (score 0):

`CompareTo` defines whether your base student is "greater than", "less than", or "equal to" your `studentToCompare`, and you can define these with any criteria you please.

more information can be found at the [MSDN documentation site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx)

the reason you're getting errors when you don't write a `CompareTo`, is because if you didn't have one, your class wouldn't actually implement `IComparable`