# Consume from Queue with multiple threads/tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I have a producer that gets users from a resource and places them into a ConcurrentQueue, then What I want to do is using multiple consumers and process all users and get their information from another resource.

```
  public void Populate(IEnumerable<Users> users){
     _queue.Enqueue(users);
     // here single threaded
  }

  public void Process(){
     // here i want this to be processed by multiple consumers
     // say multiple threads so that I can finish processing them.
  }
```

My question is, should i use thread? task? ThreadPool?

I have seen this question: [C# equivalent for Java ExecutorService.newSingleThreadExecutor(), or: how to serialize mulithreaded access to a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661760/c-sharp-equivalent-for-java-executorservice-newsinglethreadexecutor-or-how-t)

Comment: Use whichever you want; they can all do the job.  Note that they are built on top of each other.  A Task uses the thread pool (generally) and a thread pool is implemented using threads.

Comment: @Servy: just to add that while they can all do the job, in the general case if there is some relations between tasks like continuation or branching it's better to use a higher level API like the TPL which moreover seamlessly integrates with the new **await/async** feature of C# 4.5.

Comment: @Pragmateek At the end of the day it's entirely personal preference.  If someone finds it easier to use `Thread` for everything rather than task, they can do so.  Most people seem to find tasks easier to work with, but that's just an opinion.  It also depends on the problems; some problems are better suited for different abstractions.  Also note that there are a lot of parallization frameworks/abstractions besides just those three, some in the BCL and many 3rd party extensions/replacements.

Comment: There is also parallel foreach, my question is what s the best practice here?

Comment: @DarthVader: like *Servy* said this is above all a matter of personal preferences. From an academic point of view I think it's best to first master the low-level stuff like threads, then move to higher level abstractions like the TPL because they can allow you to write more readable code and in a more productive way.

Comment: @DarthVader And my response was that you can use whatever you want.  It's a subjective question with no objective answer.  Such questions are not appropriate on Stack Overflow, which is why this question should be closed.  It's "Not Constructive".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using a queuing mechanism already, I suggest you use a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) instead of `ConcurrentQueue`, along with [`Parallel.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx).

There are some important things about `BlockingCollection` that make it nice to use.

1. BlockingCollection lets the consuming threads take items from the collection in a threadsafe and natural manner using `foreach`.
2. The consuming `foreach` loop blocks automatically when the queue is empty, and continues when items become available.
3. BlockingCollection provides an easy-to-use mechanism to signal the end of data. The queue owner simply calls `queue.CompleteAdding()` and any `foreach` loops taking items from the queue will exit automatically when the queue becomes completely empty.

You can use `Parallel.Invoke()` to start a number of threads, each of which uses `foreach` to iterate over the queue. (`Parallel.Invoke()` lets you give it an array of tasks to run in parallel, which makes it quite simple to use.)

This is best illustrated with a sample program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class User
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    class Program
    {
        readonly BlockingCollection<User> _queue = new BlockingCollection<User>();

        void run()
        {
            var background = Task.Factory.StartNew(process); // Start the processing threads.

            // Make up 50 sample users.
            var users = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(n => new User{Name = n.ToString()});

            foreach (var user in users) // Add some sample data.
                _queue.Add(user);

            Console.WriteLine("Press <RETURN> to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            _queue.CompleteAdding(); // Makes all the consuming foreach loops exit.
            background.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Exited.");
        }

        void process() // Process the input queue,
        {
            int taskCount = 4;  // Let's use 4 threads.
            var actions = Enumerable.Repeat<Action>(processQueue, taskCount);
            Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
        }

        void processQueue()
        {
            foreach (User user in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                processUser(user);
        }

        void processUser(User user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing user " + user.Name);
            Thread.Sleep(200); // Simulate work.
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need to limit the number of concurrent threads and are happy to let .Net decide for you (not a bad idea), then you can simplify the code quite a bit by removing `processQueue()` altogether and changing `process()` to:

```
void process() // Process the input queue,
{
    Parallel.ForEach(_queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), processUser);
}
```

However, that does more locking than it needs to, so you're probably best off just using the original method (which doesn't suffer from that problem), or using the solution described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx

Comment: BTW, `Parallel.ForEach(_queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()` uses locks more than it has to. And the chunking `Parallel.ForEach` does doesn't work well with `GetConsumingEnumerable()`either. If either of those is a problem for you, you should use [`GetConsumingPartitioner()` from ParallelExtensionsExtras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) instead.